# Unlink all but one filetype

Tags: php, unlink, rmdir

How can I remove ALL but .sql file extensions in a specific folder with php? It's a php file that is supposed to create a backup of the database and place it in a back up folder but if there are any .jpg or any other extensions it should remove them from the backup folder.

Comment: Using the code you profided us (nothing), browse the folder manually and sort on .SQL, delete the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
$path = "backup/";

foreach(glob($path ."*.*") as $file) {
    $location = explode(".",$file);
    $extension = $location[count($location)-1];
    if($extension != "sql"){
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

---

One liner:

```
foreach(glob("backup/*") as $file) {    
    if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != "sql") unlink($file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (glob("/path/to/folder/*") as $filename) {
    if(!pathinfo($filename)['extension'] == "sql"){
        unlink($filename);
    }
}
```

We use `glob` to final all files (`*`) inside `/path/to/folder/`
Then we check is the file extension **isn't** `sql` using `!pathinfo($filename)['extension'] == "sql"`, if true, we delete the file.

Comment: Please try to add some explanation rather than just code. I know that it speaks to itself when you're experienced with it (as I am as well), but this will be seen by many, many people in it's lifetime. It came up in the LQ queue.